# Uncaught (in promise) CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 21 44 4f @+0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, ubuntu-18.04, webpacker

I am getting the following error while running my Ruby on rails 6 app on locale (Ubuntu 18.04 using chrome):

```
Uncaught (CardanoSerializationLib.ts:15  in promise) CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 21 44 4f @+0
```

and

```
GET http://localhost:3000/wasm/csl-v10.0.4.wasm 404 (Not Found)
```

and

```
`WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming` failed because your server does not serve wasm with `application/wasm` MIME type. Falling back to `WebAssembly.instantiate` which is slower. Original error:
 TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': HTTP status code is not ok
```

Seems like it is affecting webpacker, and cannot render my pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like disabling Eternl wallet extension might be a temp fix while the team looks into it:
https://github.com/ccwalletio/tracker/issues/119

Comment: Yes:
-Disable Etern extensions in Chrome
-Restart chrome  and it works.
 thanks